# How to setup a "last day of month" schedule in Networker?

Tags: backup, emc

I need to set up a "Last day of the month" schedule in EMC Networker V8.0.1

I have actually set up it as:

```
Period: Week
Action: skip skip skip skip skip skip skip
Override: full last day every month
```

But when I go back to **Show Schedule as Calendar**, it happens that "last day" is not working properly:

- January: 31 OK
- February: 28 OK
- March: 28 **WRONG**
- April: 30 OK
- May: 30 **WRONG**
- June: 30 OK
- July: 30 **WRONG**
- August: 31 OK
- September: 30 OK
- October: 30 **WRONG**
- November: 30 OK
- December: 30 **WRONG**

I have also tested with Month period, and with "full -1 day every month", with same results.

Also, I have checked documentation and it reads:

> The use of "last" for number is  not
>                 supported (for example, "last friday" cannot be used to refer to
>                 the last Friday of the month).

...but it works, and does not work properly.

Putting twelve overrides would not be right, because it will catch february 28th every year even for leap years.

So the question is, how can I make such a schedule work?

Answer (score 1):

I would schedule the tasks for 12:00am on the first of every month. I'm sorry I cannot remedy your problem in full!

Answer (score 1):

According to EMC (chat), you need to upgrade to any release level of Networker 18.2 (bug id: Bug NW- I -1042). Don't bother looking for a description of the bug id, you won't find it.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't help but to confirm your issue: https://community.emc.com/thread/133054.

So other than specifying the dates manually and then adjusting on leap year for 2/29, it looks like this is already a known issue.  You could open a ticket with EMC TAC, but you might end up right back to the above, creating the backups for those dates in the schedule manually.